# Javascript(0) along with external Javascript in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if could anyone help me. I'm stuck with this code where my script toggles the button when I click it and when I click outside the toggled window, it'll disappear, after 2 hours of searching and testing out. I still can't figure it out.
currently the script doesn't even work where the toggled menu doesn't even come out. 
When running external JSscript like the TopMenuScript.js 
it says referance error, function not defined
ReferenceError: DropdownFunction is not defined

HTML5

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tutorial_Site.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    #form1 {
        width: 1021px;
    }
    .TopPanel {}
    body,html{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .TopBannerImage {
        background:url(../Images/topPanel_3croped.png) center;
        height:315px;
        min-width:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<link href="CssFiles/MainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>
<body style="background-color:#3F3939" class ="Test">
<div id="TopPanelMenuDiv" style="background-color:black;">
    <ul id="ul_Top">
        <li><a class ="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li style="float:right !important"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class ="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="DropdownFunction()">Dropdown</a>
<div class="dropdown-content" id="MenuDropdown">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="TopBannerImage">

</div>
<!--All Site Scripts -->
<!-- <script>

    function DropdownFunction() {
        document.getElementById("MenuDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function (e) {
        if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script> -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/TopMenuScript.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
 <script>

    function DropdownFunction() {
        document.getElementById("MenuDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function (e) {
        if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

External Script link with the same script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/TopMenuScript.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

css

```
    .TopPanel
{
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image url(../Images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    height: 49px;
}
li{
    float:left;
}
li a, .dropbin {
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li a, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color:black;
}
li.dropdown {
    display:inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width:160px;
    box-shadow : 0px 8px 16px 0px RGBA(0,0,0,0.2)
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color:black;
    padding:12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.show {display:block;}
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't post the css

Comment: added css. was trying for the past 10 mins. didn't know every line had to have 4 spaces

Comment: Your JS toggles the 'show' class, yet you don't indicate what the 'show' class does in your css? Is this an accidental ommission?

Comment: my bad, it got cut off.

Comment: my apologies, new to this site not really clear with it.

Comment: Can you indicate at what point in your HTML page that `<script>` block is included?

Comment: at the very bottom before the body ends

Comment: I have just recreated the above on JSFiddle and it works fine. Can you edit the html block? It looks to me like you should have closed off the `<li>`, `<ul>` and `<div>` tags, but you have not included that. Have you definitely done that?

Comment: yes i have. i think i'll re-edit with the entire HTML5 that only includes the settings, since there are BG images and etc. it'll screw some stuff up while loading.

Comment: Why are you loading jquery 3 times? loading jquery more than once is known to cause issues .Also i would suggest you to include all you custom javascript code in `$(document).ready( function(){   /* all you custom code */ })`

Comment: it's kinda because i can't seem to fix this error and after reading.
just put the Jquery there but still getting the error of 
ReferenceError: Dropdown Function is not defined

Comment: Wait a second; does your .js file contain the `<script>` tag?

Comment: in html yes, 
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/TopMenuScript.js" ></script>

Comment: But what I'm asking is this: does 'TopMenuScript.js' contain a `<script>` tag, or just the javascript code on its own

Comment: just the javascript code on it's on.

Comment: What browser are you using to test it?

Comment: Newest firefox and Chromes, both don't work

Comment: Do you know how to use the developer tools?

Comment: i use firebug for firefox

Comment: Ok, I don't use firebug, so I can help you better in [Chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Once you have opened the dev tools, check the console. If some of those links (e.g. your JS file) aren't being found, the 404 error will be reported here. Please indicate what the console says

Comment: Also, is your site on a root domain, (like `http://www.google.com/`) or a subdomain (like `http://www.google.com/this/sub/domain`). If you are testing on a local server is it `http://localhost` or `http://localhost/folder/here`

Comment: WebForm1:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: DropdownFunction is not definedonclick @ WebForm1:35

local server and it's on VS. since it's on VS i believe directing it to the folder and file directly is correct?

Comment: @Alvin.T What is the URL you are using to access it though?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've cleaned up and fixed everything for you. Ran it in visual studio 2015 and it works just fine, fixed your UI as well.  Main cause of problem, Syntax errors and Spelling errors. 
you wanna make sure no syntax errors occurs in the javascript. one wrong synxtax and it'll cause it. i believe we're seeing errors that we're not seeing on your page.
in coding it's case sensitive
-continue coding regardless how much you fail as there's no end in learning

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tutorial_Site.WebForm1" %>
```

Your HTML5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    #form1 {
        width: 1021px;
    }
    .TopPanel {}
    body,html{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .TopBannerImage {
        background:url(../Images/topPanel_3croped.png) center;
        height:315px;
        min-width:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<link href="CssFiles/MainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>
<body style="background-color:#3F3939" class ="Test">
<div id="TopPanelMenuDiv" style="background-color:black;">
    <ul id="ul_Top">
        <li><a class ="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li style="float:right !important"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class ="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="DropdownFunction()">Dropdown</a>
<div class="dropdown-content" id="MenuDropdown">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="TopBannerImage">

</div>
<!--All Site Scripts -->
<!-- <script>

    function DropdownFunction() {
        document.getElementById("MenuDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function (e) {
        if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script> -->
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/TopMenuScript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your JavaScript Code

```
function DropdownFunction() {
    document.getElementById("MenuDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your css code

```
    .TopPanel
    {
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image url(../Images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 49px;
    }
    li{
    float:left;
}
    li a, .dropbin {
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;

}
    li a, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color:black;
}
    li.dropdown {
    display:inline-block;
}
    .dropdown-content {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width:160px;
    box-shadow : 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}
    .dropdown-content a {
    color:white;
    padding:12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
    .dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
    body{margin:0;padding:0;}
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color:#f1f1f1}
    .show {display:block;}


    #BannerImage {
    background-image: url('/Images/topPanel_3croped.png');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

    #my-div{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: His code as provided in the question works just fine when literally dropped into JSFiddle. You cannot have fixed the problem he is having...

Comment: i replaced all my codes with his. it fixed it. it's currently working already